# Test function which reads from `json` file

Tags: javascript, json, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a util file, which imports and checks given sectionUUID has a video in the `json` file.

```
import multipleVideos from '../data/videos.json'

function hasSectionMultipleVideos (sectionUUID) {
  return multipleVideos.videos.some(({ fields }) => {
    return fields.sectionUUID === sectionUUID
  })
}
```

The problem is when I try to test this function(`util.test.js`), since it doesn't accept `multipleVideos` data read from the `json` as an input, how can I test this in jest, by giving my own multiple videos data.

Comment: I am not clear about your question.

Comment: @slideshowp2 how can I test this util function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import multipleVideos from './videos.json';

function hasSectionMultipleVideos(sectionUUID) {
  return multipleVideos.videos.some(({ fields }) => {
    return fields.sectionUUID === sectionUUID;
  });
}

export { hasSectionMultipleVideos };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { hasSectionMultipleVideos } from './';

describe('61259592', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const sectionUUID = 1;
    const actual = hasSectionMultipleVideos(sectionUUID);
    expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

`videos.json`:

```
{
  "videos": [
    {
      "fields": { "sectionUUID": 1 }
    },
    {
      "fields": { "sectionUUID": 2 }
    },
    {
      "fields": { "sectionUUID": 3 }
    }
  ]
}
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61259592/index.test.ts (13.22s)
  61259592
    ✓ should pass (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.07s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61259592

Comment: Thanks, but `videos.json` is not a static file.

Comment: It'll update when the app starts, by fetching data from the server.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Can you provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code?